# Renaming a ddev project

Tags: ddev

We are a group of developers that work on multiple ddev projects. Some of these projects have a "." in their name, which by now breaks the PhpStorm integration.

Is there an easy way to rename a project and allow all other developers to tell ddev (after they pulled the new ddev config.yaml), what the previous project name was, so data (like database) could be migrated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please use the instructions in the [DDEV FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/faq/#how-can-i-change-a-projects-name) "How can I change a project's name?"

Use this process:

1. Export the database of the project: `ddev export-db --file=/path/to/db.sql.gz`
2. `ddev delete <project>`. By default this will make a snapshot, which is a nice safety valve.
3. Rename the project: `ddev config --project-name=<new_name>`
4. `ddev start`
5. `ddev import-db --src=/path/to/db.sql.gz`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I'm doing the rename like described and commit the config.yaml with the new project name, another project member might get in trouble. After doing a git pull and ddev start, their database is missing because of the name change. They need to know to backup the database before the git pull or checking out an earlier commit.

This might be much communication when there are 10+ projects that needs their names changed and 4-5 project members for each project.

But I guess its an edge case :)

Comment: Maybe that PhpStorm problem will get fixed soon. We can hope!

Comment: Between stages 2 and 3 I also renamed the project folder using `mv old_name new_name`. I guess many users would want the folder name to match the new project name. Should that be added to the DDEV FAQ?

Comment: I always want the folder name to match the project, but it's not essential. I think people can figure this step out themselves probably.